# How can I override the default css of the Apex Charts tooltip title?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, apexcharts

I am using Apex Charts and the tooltip title for each series is blue and green by default. I have been looking everywhere for how to change it and I can only figure out how to change the background color. How can I override the default settings?

[image: Here is the current title. I want to change the blue to green.]

Answer (score 0):

The colors property within options:

colors: ["#00E396"]